# How can I restrict user login/authetication access to specific applications within a single tenant?

Tags: fusionauth

I have a single Tenant with four (4) Applications and ten (10) Users defined. I want 3 users to have login access to all four Applications, and 7 users to have login access to only of the 2 applications. However, it appears that anytime I add a user to the Tenant the user receives "login/authentication" rights to all 4 applications.

Before installing and setting-up FusionAuth, I thought I would be able to use the "Groups" feature to create a group called "Group-A" that would "grant" login access to all 4 applications and another group called "Group-B" with "grant" login access to only 2 applications. I would assign the 10 users to either Group-A or Group-B and limit which user could login/authenticate to a particular application.

This capability does not appear to exists. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

FusionAuth supports this model. We call this Registrations and if a user is has a Registration for an Application, they will be allowed to access it. If they don't have a Registration for that Application, they will be logged in, but won't be granted access to the Application.

The specific implementation depends on your integration with FusionAuth:

If you are using the OAuth interface, when FusionAuth redirects back to your application, it will pass along a parameter called `userState`. This is a hint back to your application as to whether or not the user is registered for it. If the value of this parameter is `AuthenticatedNotRegistered`, you should not allow access to the application.

Additionally, if you are using the OAuth workflow, when you exchange the authorization code for a token, this token will not include the Application id or any roles that the user has for the Application.

If you are using the `/api/login` API, then the response will contain a status code of `202` that indicates that the user was authenticated but not registered for the application. Similarly, the JWT that this API returns will also not include the Application id or any roles.

Here are the doc pages for the OAuth and Login API:

- https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/endpoints#authorization-code-grant-request
- https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/login